# How do I optimize this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

Can anyone here help me to optimize this assembly code? I'm trying to make it execute faster than it is now, but I can't find any other way to do it.

```
        code:
            mov eax, x
            mov a, eax
        again :
            mov ecx, a
            shr ecx, 1
            cmp ecx, 2
            jb skip
            mov ebx, 2
            inc ecx
            sub ecx, ebx
            mov count, 0
        repeat :
            mov eax, a
            sub edx,edx
            div ebx
            sub dx,0
            jnz finish
            inc count
        finish :
            inc ebx
            loop repeat
            mov ecx,count 
            cmp ecx,max
            jbe done
            mov max, ecx
            mov eax,a
            mov num,eax
        done :
        skip :
            mov ecx, y
            inc ecx
            sub ecx, a
            inc a

        loop again
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is extremely hard to read. Can you please format nicely for the benefit of your readers? You can edit and preview your posts. Also, do you know what this loop is supposed to do?

Comment: The first optimization question is, "What is <this bit of code> supposed to do?"  Most of the people you want to help aren't going to spend a lot of time guessing.  You should write down what you know, and especially add *comments* to your code indicating what each instruction contributes to the result (don't tell us what the instruction *does*; we already know that).

Comment: I suppose "Run it on a faster processor" isn't a helpful suggestion?

Comment: if the above code works then it should be asked [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @icabod:  Yes, I'm sure OP would not consider that a helpful suggestion due to its obviousness.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how `edx` mysteriously comes into the picture, only for it to get constantly subtracted from itself (turns to 0), and then on top of that, the code  subtracts 0 from it later on.  I wonder how this code was originally generated?

Answer (score 0):

There are several redundant lines in your code, like for example:

```
        mov ebx, 2
        inc ecx
        sub ecx, ebx
```

is identical to:

```
        mov ebx, 2
        dec ecx
```

etc...
But writing it nicely will not speed it up at all on modern CPU, as those redundant lines cost you almost nothing (or really nothing).

The loop looks to run uselessly long, if I understand it (looks like you are counting number of divisors of x, so going till sqrt(x) is enough, but you go till (x/2) ).

Anyway I didn't bother to decipher fully what is it supposed to calculate. If you dare to enlighten us what that function should calculate, we may propose eventually faster algorithms (which can make it faster, as opposed to just changing x86 instructions - the gains would be negligible there).

Comment: Actually, instructions selection can *hugely* impact performance. For example, `inc` and `dec` instructions murder OoO-execution due to partial flag updates. On the other hand, `div` can have a latency of more than a hundred cycles on a modern cpu, swamping all other instructions in the code. Either way, a decent compiler would emit much better code than this.

Comment: "On the P4 use ADD/SUB in place of INC/DEC. Generally it is faster. ADD/SUB runs in 0.5 cycles. INC/DEC takes 1 cycle. "
So you are right. But in OP it doesn't matter, because he first should have written clean (in algorithm way) version, then you can optimize it by profiling. In OP there's so much wrong going on, that that final 0.5t difference is completely negligible. And again even in optimal routine this 0.5t is wasted, if you miss L0 cache page or your algorithm is simply too tight and you can't do anything meaningful OoO. So I would definitely not use word *hugely*.